# Why My onActivityResult Block Can't Handle The Data

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, android-intent, onactivityresult

I am trying to get my data from Activity to Fragment but couldn't be able to do it ı think there is a problem about requestCodes and resultCodes but o couln't find it. I made a little research but the answers didn't help me.

My companion objects in the fragment

```
companion object {
    const val REQUEST_PERMISSION = 1001
    const val REQUEST_MULTIPLE_PERMISSION = 1002
    const val REQUEST_TO_POST = 1003
}
```

Fragment to activity

```
view.testButton.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent (activity, ReaderActivity::class.java)
        startActivityForResult(intent,101)
    }
```

Activity to fragment

```
card_results = result;
    Log.d(TAG, "ResultActivity data is :" + result);
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra("cardResult", card_results );
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
    finish();
```

Fragment functions to handle data

```
 private fun getDataFromNFC(intent: Intent){
    Log.d(TAG, "getDataFromNFC: start")
    try {
        val result:String = intent.getStringExtra("cardResult").toString()
        Log.d(TAG, "getDataFromNFC data is : $result")
    }catch (e: NullPointerException){
        Log.d(TAG, "error: $e")
        Toast.makeText(activity,"Add a card",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "getDataFromNFC: ends")
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: start")
    if (requestCode == 101) {
        when (requestCode) {
            REQUEST_PERMISSION -> {
                if (data != null) {
                    getDataFromNFC(data)
                }
            }
            REQUEST_MULTIPLE_PERMISSION -> {
                // Do something if success / failed
            }
            REQUEST_TO_POST -> {
                // Parse result and do something
            }
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: ends")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only request code you are using is 101 when you use this code: `startActivityForResult(intent,101)`.

Then in `onActivityResult`, you first check if the request code is 101, which is fine, but then you have a `when(requestCode)` block that does stuff only if the request code is not 101, which will never be true for any of those cases, especially inside an if-block that already guaranteed that the request code is 101.

Also, it should be noted that `startActivityForResult()` is now deprecated in favor of [Activity Result APIs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result).

Comment: I realized that I did not use the constant request codes I created in place, so I changed my request code 101 with request permission when my block became operational. Or as same, 101 got changed by REQUEST_PERMISSION at everywhere. And thanks for letting me know about the deprecation of startActivityForResult()